# How do I make an exception to a mod rewrite rule?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I absolutely do not understand mod rewrite or the syntax to make it work. I have however managed to cobble together the following, which works exactly as I need it to on my site:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

it changes **www.mysite.com/one** into **www.mysite.com/page.php?page=one**

wonderful.

However, is there a way that I can add an exception to the rule, so that if I try to use the url www.mysite.com/feed for example, it will go to **www.mysite.com/feed/index.php** rather than trying to redirect to **www.mysite.com/page.php?page=feed**

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. Probably best would be to add a `RewriteCond` above the `RewriteRule`. Something like this (untested):

```
RewriteCond !^feed
RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If you can't get that to work then you could also put a different RewriteRule above your one to redirect before this rule is matched...

Comment: I couldn't get the !^feed to work, but your second suggestion did using RewriteRule ^feed/$ feed/index.php [L] Thanks!